# Limit Error Apexpages.Message

Tags: apex, visualforce

I get an exception error when a button is clicked and tries to insert an event record. This is expected in that users are doing something I don't want them to. However, two messages appear one that is the system validation rule and then the error on the insert. Is there a way to only show one message?

From this?
[image]

To this?
[image]

I've been playing with severity but I don't seem to be getting the syntax right.

```
 try{
        insert event;   
    }
    Catch(DMLException ex){
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, ex.getMessage()));

    }
    return null;
    try{
```

Comment: you can replace ex.getMessage() with your own custom message and it will be displayed as single error message

Comment: Are you doing `try`/`catch`? Can you show us more context?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I edited to show my try/catch

Comment: @DanWooding any luck with `getDmlMessage()` method of the DMLException ?. As mentioned in my answer.

Comment: The pattern that often works best and involves least code is to use the [ApexPages.addMessages(exceptionThrown)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_apexpages.htm) method and directly pass it the DmlException.

Comment: @KeithC That's a clean solution.I'll updated the answer with your info.

Comment: @Praveen Think it would work here but not certain.

Comment: @KeithC I tested your solution, it worked perfectly..

Comment: I tested as well. works fine. Only the one error is listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `try/catch` block and get the appropriate exception messages using DMLException's `getDmlMessage`.More methods can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm).

```
try{
    insert new Event(Subject = 'Name');
}
catch(DmlException de) {
    Integer numErrors = de.getNumDml();
    for(Integer i=0;i<numErrors;i++) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, de.getDmlMessage(i))); 
    }
}
```

@KeithC Suggested a clean and robust way, to show exception in using `ApexPages.addMessages()`.Click here to know [more](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_apexpages.htm).

```
try{
    insert new Event(Subject = 'Name');
}
catch(DmlException ex) {
   ApexPages.addMessages(ex); 
}
```

Comment: @DanWooding Glad I could help :-)

Comment: You should catch `DMLException`, not generic `Exception`. We used to call that a "pokemon catch" as in "gotta catch em all!" If you know a specific type you are expecting, catch only that type.

Comment: Lol, Ya I totally agree.I have updated the answer.Thanks for pointing out @AdrianLarson